# adding google maps to background settings with search function

Tags: maps, draw.io

i am trying to find a way to add google maps as a background to draw.io

i need more then just a screenshot of a map.. i need google maps coded into the background as a tool they can tick to enable along with a location search feature..

and instead of a background grid it will be google maps that you can drag shapes and images onto..

i just am not sure what the best approach is... any help will be much appreciated.

below is a image of what i mean
https://ibb.co/r59xYhS

Comment: In my opinion, this post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: I just would like an opinion what way would you best approach this and what files need to be edited.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/tree/master/javascript/examples/map-background and https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/map.html

Comment: Much appreciated, This will help me a great deal. Thank you.